# Sort hash by length of values (descending)

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I'm having problems sorting a hash by the length of the array values in descending order. I have the following hash:

```
hash = {
  "1" => [0,3],
  "2" => [0,2],
  "3" => [1,2,3,4],
  "4" => [1,8,7,6,5],
  "5" => [7,8],
  "10" => [5]
}
```

I want to sort it to be in this order: 4,3,1,2,5,10.

```
hash.sort_by {|k,v| v.length}.reverse
```

What am I not doing right? Any ideas?

Comment: Here it works properly! :/

Comment: @nersoh I tried running it and it gave me 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10 although 5 only has a length of 2 :(

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? A rush to judgement may discourage other, sometimes better, answers, and imo is discourteous to those still preparing answers. I suggest waiting at least a couple of hours. Just don't forget. New members often do not realize that you can vote on answers to their own questions and, once given, can withdraw the checkmark or reassign it to a different answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** sort a hash - that might be causing your confusion. There is no "internal" ordering of elements of a hash as it appears in an array.

You **can**, however, *iterate over a hash in a certain order*, e.g.

```
hash.sort_by {|k,v| v.length}.reverse.each do |k, v|
  puts "k = #{k}, v = #{v}"
end
```

Comment: One should note that the result of hash.sort_by is an array and not a hash anymore.

Comment: "There is no "internal" ordering of elements of a hash as it appears in an array." This is incorrect. As of 1.9 Ruby implemented ordering in Hashes to preserve insertion order. *Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted.* (Straight from the [Hash docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) for 1.9.3) You clearly showed you can Sort a Hash by converting it to an `Enumerator` using `Enumerable#sort_by` which will return an associated Array (with a block). This Array can then easily be converted back to a Hash and preserve the requested ordering.

Comment: @engineersmnky: You are right. Anyway, in most use cases creating a second hash for the sake of sorting is not needed, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are looking for `Enumerable#sort_by` like this (as a note, this could be `hash.sort_by {|_,v| -v.length}.to_h` depending on the Ruby version. I used `Hash[]` because of it's compatibility).

```
Hash[hash.sort_by {|_,v| -v.length}]
#=>
# {
#   "4"=>[1, 8, 7, 6, 5],
#   "3"=>[1, 2, 3, 4],
#   "1"=>[0, 3],
#   "2"=>[0, 2],
#   "5"=>[7, 8],
#   "10"=>[5]
# }
```

Sorting a `Hash` using `Enumerable#sort_by` will return an associative array of `[[key,value],[key,value],...]` when called with a block (otherwise it returns an `Enumerator`). Since `Hash` understands associative `Array` structure, you can easily turn this back into a `Hash` by calling `associative_array.to_h` (Ruby >= 2.1) or `Hash[associative_array]` (for all Ruby Versions).

Comment: @CarySwoveland @sawa took care of that for me :). Although I hate the use of `hash` as a local variable name since it already has a meaning as a method in the context of Object